# 2011 Jeep Compass replaced TIPM module used with same part number fuse 23 26 no power asd relay box ok scan no communication

Tags: jeep, compass, totally-integrated-power-module

Does TIPM module have to be programmed  some modules work there was a fire TIPM  circuit board  thats why i replaced it no wires burned  scanned and checked no communication with ecm transmission brake instrument cluster

Answer (score 0):

If replacing with the SAME part number, **you DO NOT need to program it**.
It will relearn the VIN itself and the main configuration settings will already be the same. If you are replacing with a different part then the VIN will learn but you must use a proper tool to reconfigure it for the functions of your model. Not all part numbers are compatible even if after configuring them properly since the internal hardware is different. So keep it simple and always match part number (ignoring the last letter in part# is Ok)

After install you turn the ignition to ON for about 10 seconds and then turn it back off, that is it.

The issue's you are still having sounds like you have picked a faulty unit or your issue's are outside of the TIPM but it is very commonly failing part. One of the most repaired units I have come in the shop.

Answer (score -1):

A TIPM is in intelligent module and it must know the exact spec of your vehicle in order to operate properly. It must know the exact VIN of your vehicle and that requires programming with a professional scan tool. Generally speaking, ALL intelligent modules, regardless of manufacturer, need to be programmed to the vehicle's VIN. In fact, in later model vehicles, especially GM vehicles, if you swap in a junkyard part, you'll brick every module on the data bus. Take it to any shop that does programming and pay them to programm it with your VIN.

If you're replacing a module in the future, skip the junk yard and buy a rebuilt module from a rebuilder instead. They'll program it to your VIN before shipping.

Comment: All I can find says it does not need programming, do you have any links saying otherwise?

Comment: While not disagreeing with your answer, a good answer would include how one would go about doing this and what is used to make it happen. Obviously the OP didn't know it would need to be done, so help here would make this a MUCH better answer.

Comment: Edit your answer with the new information. Don't put it in comments.

Comment: Most all chrysler modules will self learn VIN. Pretty much everything except PCM and SKIM's. It actually even causes a lot of issue's when installing used PCM's because sometimes your original modules can sniff out the VIN from it and rewrite your original with the donors. I have to reset tons of radios because they get locked from improperly sniffing and storing the wrong VIN..
Side note: There is nothing intelligent about TIPMS. They are one of the poorest designed and functioning modules I know of.